# How to shows only "X" images from a post (on a taxonomy page), if the number of the attachment images in the current post more than like "X"?

Tags: image, attachment

I have a multisite network, users uploads posts, and horrible, when a user attached more that 10 images to a post, because this will be very long, and extends down to the 4.-5. page on the masonry layout... So I want that, If a post has more that 3 attachments (images), on my network's homepage (and taxonomy pages) the post shows it with only the first 3 images, and with a link to the full post.
So I have this code:

```
   $attachments = get_children(
       array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
       ));
   if(count($attachments) > 3) { ?>
       <!-- Code need to here, what shows only the first 3 images -->
   <?php } else {
       the_content();
         } ?>
```

I'm looking for a solution on the net, but for the time being I dont find anything. If you can help me, please write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works on subdomain based multisites with reblogged (broadcasted, or any) childposts, what dont have original content (because it gets it from their parent).

1. add to your function.php:

   ```
     // ADD IMAGES TO the_expert
     function improved_trim_excerpt($text) {
        global $post;
        if ( '' == $text ) {
                $text = get_the_content('');
                $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
                $text = strip_tags($text, '<a><img>');

               $delim = '</a>'; // I think you also want add links to your images
               $start = 0; // starter image
               $items = 3; // number of images
               $the_excerpt = implode($delim, array_slice(explode($delim, $text), $start,$items)) . $delim; // $delim closes your excerpt
        }
        return $the_excerpt;
     }
     remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
     add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_trim_excerpt');
   ```
2. And the part of your content page:

   ```
     global $post;
     $postid = ($id == $post->ID) ? $post->ID : $id;
     $content = $post->post_content;
     // match all urls
     preg_match_all( '/(http:|https:)?\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?/', $content, $matches );
     $count = 0;
     if ( ! empty( $matches ) && ! empty( $matches[ 0 ] ) ) {
         foreach ( $matches[ 0 ] as $url ) {
             $split    = explode( '#', $url );
             $split    = explode( '?', $split[ 0 ] );
             $split    = explode( '&', $split[ 0 ] );
             $filename = basename( $split[ 0 ] );
             $file_type = wp_check_filetype( $filename, wp_get_mime_types() );
             if ( ! empty ( $file_type[ 'ext' ] ) ) {
                 // (optional) limit inclusion based on file type
                 if( ! in_array( $file_type[ 'ext' ], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'webp', 'bmp')) ) continue;
                 $files[ $url ] = $file_type;
                 $urls[]=$url;
                 $count ++;
             }
         }
     }
     $no_of_photos = $count / 2; // Gets the number of photo's attached in $no_of_photos variable -> you need use / 2, if your image's links shows to the file, because in this case, in every <img> have two 'ext'.
     $limit_photos = 3; // set your limit

                 if( $no_of_photos <= $limit_photos ) {
                 the_content(); ?>
                 } else {
                 the_excerpt(); ?>
                 }
   ```

Special thanks for @Andreas:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609326/9565969

And @jgraup:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246063/134567

Comment: oh, and I know, this is wordpress topic, I sorry, I share this on wrong site :/