# How to explode the string back from the second or third string delimiter?

Tags: php, explode

How can I get the 800-555 from this 800-555-5555 with `explode()`?

Here is a good example:

```
$rawPhoneNumber = "800-555-5555"; 

$phoneChunks = explode("-", $rawPhoneNumber);
First chunk = $phoneChunks[0]; //800
Second chunk = $phoneChunks[1]; //555
Third Chunk chunk = $phoneChunks[2]; //5555
```

But how can I get the 800-555?

Okay, I see, here need more comment... So, this is only an example... In real I add a word (now $word) to string delimiter and my string is a full article... I want that, if this word second time published in the article, with `str_word_count()` will count, how many characters was in the text to the second (or third, if I want that) `$word`...

So I want that, I get the string from the second "hit" to back.

Okay, here is a more obvious example:

```
$text = oh my god, thank you the lot of downvotes, geniuses *.*
$explode = explode(",", $text);
$whatiwant = $explode?? // I WANT THE STRING FROM THE SECOND "," TO BACK
```

So I want that `$whatiwant = oh my god, thank you the lot of downvotes`

Comment: You can either simply concatenate the 800 and the 555 with a hyphen, or you need to use a Regular Expression instead of the ``explode()`` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Implode`, `explode` and `array_slice`.
I use `array_slice` because that makes the function more dynamic.

Now you can just set the `$items` to get the number of items you want.
If you set a negative value it counts backwards.

```
$delim = ",";
$items =2;
$text = "oh my god, thank you the lot of downvotes, geniuses *.*";
$whatiwant = implode($delim, array_slice(explode($delim, $text),0,$items));
Echo $whatiwant;
```

https://3v4l.org/KNSC4

You could also have an start variable to make the start position dynamic.

https://3v4l.org/XD0NV

Answer (score 1):

Doing concatenation of already generated array's indexes is the simple way for you.

Sample Code

```
echo $phoneChunks[0]."-".$phoneChunks[1];
```

Comment: Sorry, there was typo :P

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$rawPhoneNumber = "800-555-5555";

$phoneChunks = explode("-", $rawPhoneNumber);
$first_chunk = $phoneChunks[0]; //800
$second_chunk = $phoneChunks[1]; //555
$third_chunk_chunk = $phoneChunks[2]; //5555

$portion_array = array($first_chunk, $second_chunk);
echo implode("-",$portion_array);
```

Output:

```
800-555
```